# How to miss Checkstyle rule for final variables?

Tags: java, android, checkstyle

I have a next rule in my checkstyle.xml :

```
 <module name="MemberNameCheck">
            <!-- Validates non-static members against the supplied expression. -->
            <metadata name="altname" value="MemberName"/>
            <property name="applyToPublic" value="true"/>
            <property name="applyToProtected" value="true"/>
            <property name="applyToPackage" value="true"/>
            <property name="applyToPrivate" value="true"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
```

It's a good one, but i don't want to apply this to the `final` variables in all my project. There are no property with name "applyToFinal".
Please, tell me, is there are any ways to achieve it.

Comment: You have a very special use case, which is probably relevant to your situation only. Afaik, Checkstyle does not offer a solution for this. You would have to write a custom check.